# "Connectionless, unconnected" connections

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, udp, client-server

I just started learning about sockets programming, and I've run into a concept I've seen before but was quite confusing to me.

It seems that UDP connections are "connectionless, unconnected" connections.

Isn't "connectionless" and "unconnected" redundant?

Are there then 4 types of connections?

i.e.

1. connectionless, unconnected
2. connectionless, connected
3. connection-oriented unconnected
4. connection-oriented, connected

And finally, how can a "connectionless, unconnected" connection function? Isn't that an oxymoron? lol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In fact, there is no such thing as an UDP connection. Basically, UDP is a fire and forget protocol, where you just send packets of data towards some machine (without needing to establish a connection first), and hoping the other machine will pick them up (if they even make it at all).

When you establish a "socket connection" nothing magical happens i.e. wires between you and your remote client don't change color or something. What happens during a connection is both sides agree to receiving and sending data reliably over the internet, with a given protocol. It is absolutely not required to be connected with anything to send and receive stuff over the internet, however connections allow you to guarantee integrity and order (and some other things) because both machines agreed to follow a certain method.

I know of no such thing as a "connectionless, unconnected" socket. Whoever told you that was probably just trying to emphasize the nonconnected aspect of UDP.

Answer (score 13):

Technically, you can call `connect()` on a UDP socket. In this case the socket remembers the peer address, so that datagrams can be send using `send()` or `write()` syscalls instead of `sendto()`. Also, it makes the socket receive datagrams only from that peer, datagrams from other peers get discarded.

May be this is what is referred to as "connectionless, connected" socket, meaning `connect()` call was invoked on a UDP socket.

Answer (score 1):

With UDP sockets, you can connect to a server as with TCP sockets. But you can also send packets directly to a server without being connected, with the [`sendto`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendto) function.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, technically UDP doesn't make connections.  However, your code may have a connection to a local UDP socket which it uses to transmit packets.

Comment: The code has a socket, or socket handle or fd. There is no 'connection' there.